# Error class expected!

Tags: java

Com este código obtenho o erro:

> error: class expected

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  

public class MenorIdade {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String[] nomes = new String[5];  
        int [] idades = new int[5];  
        int maisJovem = 0;  

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {  
            nomes[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o nome");  
            idades[i] = int.parseInt(JOptionByte.showInputDialog("Informe a idade"));

            if (idades[i] < idades[maisJovem]) {  
                maisJovem = i;  
            }
        }  

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, nomes[maisJovem] + " é mais jovem e tem " + idades[maisJovem] + " anos.");  

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modificações no código:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[] nomes = new String[5];  
    int [] idades = new int[5];  
    int maisJovem = 0;  
    String showInputDialog = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {  
        nomes[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o nome");  
        showInputDialog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a idade");
        idades[i] = Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog);
        if (idades[i] < idades[maisJovem]) {  
            maisJovem = i;  
        }
    }  
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, nomes[maisJovem] + " é mais jovem e tem " + idades[maisJovem] + " anos.");          
}
```

Comment: Seria uma forma válida, @Maria. De primeira eu não tinha entendido o porque da `String showInputDialog;` intermediária, mas acabei vendo. Mas, mesmo funcional, não é necessária, já que dá pra fazer o `parse` diretamente.

Comment: Vou editar a minha resposta para que o Camuratti possa observar as duas formas, ok?

Comment: @GustavoCinque, tranquilo faz sim...!

Comment: @GustavoCinque em relação ao `parse`, na minha opinião esse código precisa ser melhorado, porque, não há criticas no contéudo que possa ser digitado...

Comment: Hm, é que eu sempre usei dando o parse sobre o input, hehe. Rapidez na hora de escrever e ler, para mim.

Comment: Então nesse ponto eu discordo e se o cara digitar letra em vez de número? nem um bloco `try` `catch` ele colocou entendeu

Comment: Você tem razão. Se acontecesse, daria um belo `NumberFormat`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, @Maria!!

Answer (score 0):

Na linha 11:

`idades[i] = int.parseInt(JOptionByte.showInputDialog("Informe a idade"));`

Você não pode utilizar o tipo primitivo de uma classe para fazer chamada de métodos, então o correto seria `Integer.parseInt();`. Não sei se seria só comigo, mas meu IDE(Eclipse) não reconheceu a classe `JOptionByte`.

Uma forma seria substituir a parte `JOptionByte` e utilizar a `JOptionPane` mesmo, ficando assim:

`idades[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a idade"));`

Comment: O meu NetBeans também não reconhece. @GustavoCinque

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @GustavoCinque

Comment: @Camuratti, se você achou util alguma das respostas, valide-as como a melhor, assim você encerraria a pergunta ;)